# Java hashmap dealing with values which have identical keys

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to write a program that finds all combinations of words from a "dictionary" text file input, that are anagrams of a given word. E.g if the dictionary contained:

```
finding
anagram
s
findign
apple
```

and the given word was findinganagrams, the output would be:

```
finding anagram s
findign anagram s
```

I've taken the input, sorted each string alphabetically (e.g anagram=aaagmnr) and stored them in an array list which is then used to find all possible combinations of the words that equal the goal word. These values are also used as keys in a hashmap "dictionary" of arraylists to remember the original non-alphabetical word.

At the end of my program I have an arraylist of arrays, each array representing a solution, however they are still in the alphabetical form:

```
aaagmnr dfgiinn s <- first array
aaagmnr dfgiinn s <-second array
```

If I iterate through the arrays and print dictionary.get(word), I get output like this:

```
[anagram] [finding, findign] [s] 
[anagram] [finding, findign] [s]
```

Where each alphabetical word was a key to an array in the hashmap, and finding/findign have the same key. I know I can print dictionary.get(word).get(0) etc, but i'm stuck as to how I could go about iterating through and printing all combinations of this?

Comment: How are you ending up with two identical arrays? I would expect you would map the sorted key to a list of anagrams, and iterate the list for each solution.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], and expected output